# On AJAX-Enabled Views the "Add to Cart" button does not work properly

Tags: views, ajax

On **AJAX** enabled Views with exposed filters or pagers the "**Add to Cart**" button and "**add to wishlist**" does not work properly.

After an **AJAX call**, the add-to-cart form action changes to **views/ajax**, so if i press the button, only a **JSON** output will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. This module will be usefull for you:[Commerce Ajax Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ajax_cart)

Comment: What about the add to wishlist button